# Changing static variable works Primitive Wrapper but not with Primitive type

Tags: java, class, reflection, primitive

I have a situation where I have to change java constant.

I have below code working

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {
    public static final Integer FLAG = 44;

    static void setFinalStatic(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName, Object newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiers = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiers.setAccessible(true);
        modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("Everything is %s%n", FLAG);
        setFinalStatic(Main.class, "FLAG", 33);
        System.out.printf("Everything is %s%n", FLAG);
    }
}
```

If I run above , I get following output:

```
Everything is 44
Everything is 33
```

But if I change `FLAG` variable to int i.e.

```
public static final int FLAG = 44;
```

It does not work. The output is :

```
Everything is 44
Everything is 44
```

Is there any other way to make it work with `Primitive` Type `int`.

Comment: Why do you declare the variable final if you want to change it? Remove final.

Comment: +1 to the above comment. The easy answer is that ints are non-mutable, but I don't know enough deep java to answer with confidence

Comment: compile time constants are inlined.  If the value is not known until runtime, it can be altered.  Note: changing `final` variables is sure to cause confusion so you wouldn't actually do this in production.

Comment: The three lines involving `modifiers` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @mvmn I cannot remove it. I am using a library where I need to pass integer but it only accepts constant. The value for this should come from property file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [jls-4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression [(§15.28)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), is called a `constant variable`.

Also section [13.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) says (emphasis mine)

> 3..**References to fields that are constant variables (§4.12.4) are resolved at compile time to the constant value that is denoted**. No reference to such a field should be present in the code in a binary file (except in the class or interface containing the field, which will have code to initialize it). Such a field must always appear to have been initialized (§12.4.2); the default initial value for the type of such a field must never be observed.

It means that *compile-time constant expression* from *constant variables* will be put directly in code by compiler (it will be inlined) not read from final reference at runtime.

For instance if you execute `main` method from `Bar` class

```
class Foo{
    static{
        System.out.println("test if class will be loaded");
    }
    public static final int x = 42;
}

class Bar{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(Foo.x);
    }
}
```

you will see no output from static block of `Foo` class which means `Foo` class hasn't been loaded, which means that value of `Foo.x` didn't come from this class. In fact `Bar` was compiled this way

```
class Bar{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(42); // reference Foo.x will be removed by compiler 
                                // and replaced with actual value because
                                // compiler assumes that value can't/shouldn't
                                // change at runtime
    }
}
```

So even changing value of `Foo.x` at runtime will not affect value printed in `main` method in `Bar` class.

You can't change that mechanism.

---

Possible way around would be initializing your final fields with values created at runtime time (they wouldn't exist at compile time, which will prevent them from being *compile-time constant expressions*). So instead of

```
public static final String x = "foo";
```

try

```
public static final String x = new String("foo");
```

or in case of primitive types use Unboxing like instead of

```
public static final int x = 42;
```

use

```
public static final int x = new Integer(42);
```

Comment: Keywords to look up are constant expressions and constant variables.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you take a look at edited version or my answer? I am definitely not Java expert so I could make some simple but crucial mistakes which I am not aware of :/

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Primitive types get inlined.
2. In fact even non-primitive constants, when imported into other classes, will be copied, and the import forgotten. So there it will not work either. Only for constant caches, like the string pool, and Integer (Integer.valueOf(13)) caches you may overwrite their values.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because  static final fields of primitive or String type get inlined during compile time. The main method will looks something like this after compilation and de-compilation

```
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("Everything is %s%n", 44);
        setFinalStatic(Main.class, "FLAG", 33);
        System.out.printf("Everything is %s%n", 44);
    }
```

because FLAG gets replaced with actual value in compile-time.